# Center last line of shapepar paragraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, xetex, shapepar

I have a paragraph of text inside `\shapepar` to make it flow tightly around a custom shape (background image). The text itself is justified to both ends, however I would like to center the last line. Is that possible?

The contents of the paragraph are generated from an external data source and I need to generate lots of documents like this, so manual adjusting is not possible - it needs to happen automatically.

My code:

```
\documentclass[border=0,margin=0,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\def\myshapepar#1{\shapepar[1mm]{\myshapeshape}#1\par}
\def\myshapeshape{%
{0}
{0}b{0}\\
{0}t{-20}{40}\\
{5}t{-21}{42}\\
{10}t{-26}{52}\\
{15}t{-32}{64}\\
{20}t{-32}{64}\\
{25}t{-24}{48}\\
{25}e{0}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (105mm, 148mm); % Force page size
\node[inner sep=0,anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=148mm]{vlocka-plain.jpg}};

\node[draw=none,align=center,text width=4cm,anchor=north] at (55mm, 120mm) {\myshapepar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eget viverra orci. Sed lacinia maximus urna lobortis semper. Vestibulum a semper ante.}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result vs. wanted result:
[image: Result]
[image: Wanted]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit late at night for hacking shapepar internals but it is easy enough to fix this manually, and getting a good position perhaps needs manual control anyway to interact with the border:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0,margin=0,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\def\myshapepar#1{\shapepar[1mm]{\myshapeshape}#1\par}
\def\myshapeshape{%
{0}
{0}b{0}\\
{0}t{-20}{40}\\
{5}t{-21}{42}\\
{10}t{-26}{52}\\
{15}t{-32}{64}\\
{20}t{-32}{64}\\
{25}t{-24}{48}\\
{25}e{0}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (105mm, 148mm); % Force page size
\node[inner sep=0,anchor=south west] at (0,0) {%
%\includegraphics[height=148mm]{vlocka-plain.jpg}%
};

\node[draw=none,align=center,text width=4cm,anchor=north] at (55mm, 120mm) {\myshapepar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eget viverra orci. Sed lacinia maximus urna lobortis semper. 
\mbox{\hspace{1cm}Vestibulum a semper ante.}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of a fixed distance of `1cm` (which looks not quite centered to me), wouldn't `\hspace*{\fil}` work to counteract the `1fil` in the usual `\parfillskip`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton no doesn't work as Donald is doing all kinds of measuring boxing unboxing and re-setting to make shapepar work, and a stretchable glue looks like 0pt as natural width most of the time so doesn't do anything useful (I tried that first:-)

Comment: thanks for explanation.  it seemed worth asking.  (so ultimately, it's a matter of getting out the measuring device and doing it manually.  `1cm` is definitely not quite enough.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes or actually since the border is in fact symmetrical here it's probably easier not to use shapepar at all and just use `\centering` with `\\ ` to force line breaks as required.

Comment: Thank you for this solution but unfortunately the text itself comes from an external data source. I need to generate many of documents like this and manually breaking/offsetting the last line is not possible - it needs to be automatic. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'll update the question.

Comment: @lacop since the image border is a fixed size you could probably more easily use \parshape directly (then it's easy to center each line within that shape) otherwise it's back to hacking shapepar code but that needs a free weekend and lots of coffee:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh wow, \parshape is much easier to use and better for my use case - no idea how I have missed it. Thank you very much. I've now solved it without even using TikZ, just putting the image as background and using \parshape + \centering for the text.

As for shapepar code I agree - my plan was to modify the code to detect the last line and change the line width for it, but seeing the code made me reconsider that decision.

Comment: @lacop feel free to self-answer and accept yours (I will survive the pain of the lack of acceptance:-) it's good for the site to round things off with an accepted answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've posted mine, but it solves a different problem (centering in `\parshape`) than the question asks (`\shapepar`). So I will accept yours instead, even though it didn't work for my usecase. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In the end I went with `\parshape` instead of `\shapepar`, which didn't work in TikZ. So I used the `background` package for background image and `picture` enviroment for absolute positioning.

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{picture,rotating}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=1,
placement=top,
vshift=-1cm,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=0.99\paperwidth]{vlocka-plain-crop.jpg}
  }%
}

\newlength{\halfpage}
\setlength{\halfpage}{\dimexpr(\textwidth)/2\relax}
\newcommand{\shapeline}[1]{\dimexpr(\halfpage-\dimexpr(#1)/2) #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-0.375in,-6.3cm){
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
        \psbarcode{http://example.com/?code=code}{eclevel=L width=0.75 height=0.75}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\put(1cm,1.75cm){\turnbox{-90}{\textbf{code}}}
}
\end{picture}%
~\\[22pt]
\centering \textbf{Some title} % Nadpis priania
\\[10pt]
\begin{center}%
\parshape=6
\shapeline{120pt}
\shapeline{140pt}
\shapeline{155pt}
\shapeline{180pt}
\shapeline{200pt}
\shapeline{175pt}
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{center}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't there any automatic way to do it without manually specifying the coordinates?